# BouncyCastle pulling related dependency with different versions

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, bouncycastle

I just upgraded the Spring boot app. I was using bouncyCastle version 1.66 in my older app, no other bouncyCastle related dependecy.

```
compile ("org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk15on:1.66")
```

PGPUtil.getDecoderStream() works fine before but now it's returning 0's:

```
InputStream inputStream = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(inputStream);
```

before upgrade:
inputStream > buf
`[-88, 3, 80, 71, 80, -63, -64, .. +8,092 more]`

after upgrade:
inputStream > buf
`[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 +8,092 more]`

Please help me to resolve this issue, thanks

I run the app locally and it's unable to decrypt the data

Comment: Are you performing tests on the same data all the time? I guess it could be a bug in the internal buffer handling, but it seems far fetched.

Comment: Did you use the same JDK? Can you post the full relevant part if your test code?

Comment: I am performing test against same data but not parallel. I run both separately. Same JDK is used in both tests.